# Signal classification based on keras stateful LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

This is my first time asking on StackOverflow. If there are any issues with my English, please forgive me. Thanks

I'm doing a project that uses LSTM to classify ECG sequences. I am using the [PTB database](https://physionet.org/physiobank/database/ptbdb/). There are couples of ECG record about 38s,38000 data points (sample rate 1kHz). After downsampled, I got new sequences with 250Hz sample rate for reducing data. I've read some papers and tutorials that point out Basic LSTM could not perfectly handle long sequence dependencies(more than 400-timesteps). So I decide using the stateful LSTM. But there's a problem confuses me a lot.
One complete ECG sequence contains 38(segmented samples)x250(each sample size(1second)),but this sequences share a same `label` e.g. Myocardial Infarction.
How could I define the `train_y`when training the model? 
And should I call `model.reset_states()`at each end of a complete sequence manually e.g. after 38 samples? Or there's another way could help with this? 
If someone could help me, I will highly appreciate!

If there's something not perfectly explained, Plese correct me. Thanks!

Comment: Either the papers or your interpretation were not quite precise. There is absolutely no difference between how `stateful=True` and `stateful=False` handle the data. The only difference is the possibility to divide your sequences in small segments and make the model still see all segments as a single sequence. In your case, the only reason to use `stateful=True` is a possible memory shortage due to the size of the sequences.

Comment: @DanielMöller Thank you for your interpretation,and yes I am facing the RAM size problem, so I decide to use stateful=true  : ) Sorry for missing this information!

Comment: Ok, one question: do you want to classify one entire ECG? Or do you want to classify segments of an ECG?

Comment: One entire ECG, Thank you. Sorry that not precisely makes your inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will only need `True` if you're facing RAM issues.

**In a `stateful=False` case:**

Your `X_train` should be shaped like `(patients, 38000, variables)`. Or, in the downsampled case: `(patients, 9500, variables)`.

Your `y_train` should be shaped like `(patients, classes)`.

If your RAM problem is with the numpy arrays and your PC, go to the `stateful=True` case. But if it's an OOM allocation with the GPU, then you could try smaller batch sizes first

**In a `stateful=True` case:**

This is a very nice question indeed...

In your case, if you keep sequences that are long enough, the class should probably be noticeable in every segment, but if you do need the entire ECG to detect the problem, then this approach may not be good, and I don't know another approach at the moment.

For this approach, `X_train` should be `(patients * 38, 250, variables)`.

And for `y_train` you will need to repeat the classes for each segment: `(patients * 38, classes)`.

When fitting, you must remember to set `shuffle=False`.

And the organization of the data should be:

```
[
   patient 1 - segment 1
   patient 2 - segment 1
   patient 3 - segment 1
   ...
   patient n - segment 1
   ------------------
   patient 1 - segment 2
   patient 2 - segment 2
   ...
   --------------------
   patient 1 - segment 38
   patient 2 - segment 38
   ...
   patient n - segment 38
]
```

Use `reset_states()` every epoch.

Comment: I appreciate your help! You've solved a problem that really has been bothering me for a long time!